# Schema.org type for Document?

Tags: seo, semantics, schema.org

I'm a bit surprised there is not a defined type for a Document. Can I put a type in there that is not outlined in the [**Full Schema.org Hierarchy**](http://schema.org/docs/full.html)?

I'll probably use `Article` but it seems crazy that there isn't a type defined for documents. Such as legal documents, contracts, agreements, statement of work, NDAs, etc... Maybe a `Product`?

There is probably no right or wrong answer here, just looking for some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreativeWork` seems to be the closest.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is [DigitalDocument](https://schema.org/DigitalDocument) which is intended for electronic files and documents.